# restrict keyword ignored by the compiler when not passed as function parameters

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, restrict-qualifier

I have two functions which do the same

```
#define RES restrict

void fun1(double * tmp1, int n)
{ // In this function, compiler ignores the restrict keyword
    double * RES a = tmp1;
    double * RES b = tmp1+n;
    double * RES c = tmp1+2*n;

    for (int i =0 ; i < n; ++i) 
    {   
        a[i] += c[i]+b[i]; // loads a,b,c, stores a
        a[i] += c[i]*b[i]; // loads b,c ans stores to a
    }
}


void fun2(double * RES a, double * RES b, double * RES c, int n)
{
    // fun2(tmp1, tmp1+n, tmp1+2*n,n)
    // Compiler takes restrict into account.
    for (int i =0 ; i < n; ++i) 
    {   
        a[i] += c[i]+b[i]; // loads a,b, and 2 x c and stores in a
        a[i] += c[i]*b[i];
    }
}
```

I compile with gcc-13 with `-O3` flag. In `fun1`, the compiler ignores `restrict` keyword where as in `fun2` it reduced one load and one store instruction. From the previous answers, I see `restrict` is a hint to compiler, but do we have a way to make `fun1` generate similar instructions as `fun2`  (I mean same as with restrict ?).  Here is godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/aTzzbTqzE)

Comment: Why bother with the macro?

Comment: @Chris just to check without restrict

Comment: "do we have a way to make fun1 generate similar instructions as fun2" yes, call fun2 from fun1 https://godbolt.org/z/a1n4qfT7e

Comment: "compiler ignores the restrict keyword" --> of course.  By construction of `a,b,c`, the compiler already knows later code can assume the pointed to data of `a,b,c` do not overlap. Using `restrict` in `double * RES a = tmp1;` offers no advantage.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The assembly shows the compiler is not using that information regardless of whether it comes from `restrict` or the pointer construction. That is the issue.